# Remove the grub menu after removing Windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a Spectre x360 laptop, one which I had dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed online to remove Windows, which was a success. However, the options to boot Ubuntu or Windows still remained when I booted up.

I have seen online that I can type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to remove obsolete entries from the starting up menu. I did this, but Windows boot option still appeared.

Next I added:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

to the:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

file. This removed the Windows option, but I still got that opening menu, allowing me to choose between:

Ubuntu
Advanced Options for Ubuntu
System Settings
I just want to machine to boot up straight to Ubuntu.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that same grub configuration, there are two lines that are commented out:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Remove the # at the beginning of each line, then run sudo update-grub again.

Comment: GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true was already uncommented, but  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 wasn't. This worked, thank you.